# Linear gradient in Chrome and Safari browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, linear-gradients

I am having trouble showing a linear gradient in Safari and Chrome. In Firefox it shows up fine.

I am trying:

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #9E9E9E, #454545) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;   
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #9E9E9E, #454545) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(center top , #9E9E9E, #454545) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
background:      -o-linear-gradient(center top , #9E9E9E, #454545) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/fwkgM/1/

```css
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9e9e9e, #454545);
```

[CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/)

Comment: I removed `-image` and still works, so why did you add that ?

Comment: I think he did that because he's separating the background image from the background color.  If the `background-image` refers to a url that is not accessible the background will still fall back to the `background-color` as a default.  In this case, you found that changing `background-image` to just `background` still works, which is just evidence that there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: I just had to add -image for an angled/skewed gradient to work on safari: `background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,#F9C665, #ef3429,...etc)`

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It's a pretty good CSS3 gradient generator. It has worked well for me. Hope it helps you too! :D

Comment: That gradient editor is great.  Am I overlooking a way to specify the colours using the standard CSS colour names?  E.g. lightslategray, et al.  I can easily search-and-replace in the resulting gradient CSS to switch rgba(xyza) with the names I want, but the generated IE9 SVG data is pre-generated.

Answer (score 7):

For Cross browser compatibility try the following

```
background-color: #9e9e9e; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(213,12,18), #9e9e9e 40%); /* For Chrome 25 and Safari 6, iOS 6.1, Android 4.3 */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #9e9e9e 60%, #454545 100%); /* For Firefox (3.6 to 15) */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #9e9e9e 60%, #454545 100%); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #9e9e9e 60%, #454545 100%); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,transparent,black 50%,transparent); /* worked for me*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-attachment: fixed; /* worked for me */
```

Answer (score 0):

For me safari didn't like going from a color to `transparent`, so the only solution was go from a transparent color to a zero opacity version of the same color.

Bad

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .75), transparent);
```

Good

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
```